# Extract value from json data using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, extract, typeerror

After doing an API request I get the json 'data' this has each record in a different set if curly brackets under the results square brackets.

I want to extract the numbers and store/print them separated with a comma.

so requested output

```
0010041,0010042
```

I have tried using the below however it comes back with the following error.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

If the results only has one set of brackets it works fine, do I have to convert the multiple results into one so and then extract all the times when 'number' appears?

```
import json
import sys

#load the data into an element
data={'result': [{'number': '0010041', 'day_of_week': 'monday'}, {'number': '0010042', 'day_of_week': 'tuesday'}]}

#dumps the json object into an element
json_str = json.dumps(data)

#load the json to a string
resp = json.loads(json_str)

print (resp['result'])
print (resp['result']['number'])
```

Comment: You need to first state which item in result you want the number reg . ```esp['result'][0]['number']```

Comment: add this line ```print([i['number'] for i in resp['result']]) ``` instead of ```print (resp['result']['number'])``` in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message is clear: you are trying to access a list of dicts and you aren't doing it correctly.

Replace your last line with:

```
for i in resp['result']:
    print(i['number'])
```

Update:

As suggested in comments, you can use list comprehension. So to get your desired result, you can do:

```
print(",".join([i['number'] for i in resp['result']]))
```

Comment: You can use a list comprehension, which is a powerful feature of python to extract those numbers from list of dicts.  ```print([i['number'] for i in resp['result']])```